# Solid object using point cloud

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am doing a 3D face identification and verification project using matlab. I have already done a plot of face feature points. But I want to fill my point cloud into a solid object. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
load('myOne.mat');
figure(3)
plot3(myOne(:,1),myOne(:,2),myOne(:,3),'r.');
%3D face building
shp = alphaShape(myOne(:,1),myOne(:,2),myOne(:,3),1,'HoleThreshold',15);
plot(shp)
title('3D surface from point cloud')
```

[myOne.mat,Point cloud and Wrap 3D face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJOFO.png)

[myOne.mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQc0uU9GFaVaTRnbVBlbmxCa2M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of a face, or maybe a link to your .mat file? Otherwise have a look [here](https://github.com/markeroon/matlab-computer-vision-routines/blob/master/third_party/MyCrust100809/MyRobustCrust.m) and [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41123-pointtool/content/PointTool/Crust.m). There used to be a function called myRobustCrust.m on file exchange which works robustly for what you would like to do (triangulation, I suppose), but apparently it has been removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used myOne.mat as xyz coordinates of face. Then I plotted point cloud. Now I want to create solid object.

Comment: Can you link to a file with your actual data?

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about what you are asking. I have added my coordinates file.

Comment: Yep, but it's a picture. I need the actual data. So could you save the workspace and upload it?

Comment: The file you uploaded only contains one 2x3 matrix.

Comment: sorry..It's my mistake and check now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could download MyRobustCrust.m (author: Luigi Giaccari) for example from [github](https://github.com/markeroon/matlab-computer-vision-routines/tree/master/third_party/MyCrust100809).

Then doing

```
[t,tnorm]=MyRobustCrust(myOne(:, 1:3));
hold on; 
title('Output Triangulation','fontsize',14);
axis equal;
trisurf(t,myOne(:,1),myOne(:,2),myOne(:,3),'facecolor','c','edgecolor','b');
```

gives you

[image]

### Note of caution:

**The file used to exist on Matlab FileExchange but doesn't anymore. I don't know, why that is and I think to be on the safe side it would be best to contact the author before using it.**